# How to Edit a File(Html) which is read by the StreamReader in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-email, .net

```
   string BODY = String.Empty; 
            string PageName = @"[C:\Users\User1\Desktop\SK\Resources\HTMLEmail\email.html]";  
            BODY = new StreamReader(PageName).ReadToEnd();
```

I am reading a HTml File in my C# code using the above code, what I want to do is add some text to the file and save it or I have to send the file to a method which sends a email with the file.

the code below is from the email.html I have to add the Email Address and password in the  [Email Address] and [Password]. How can i add text to the read HTML. And how can I send it to the method after doing the edit. Thanks

```
 <tr>
       <td valign="top">
        <div mc:edit="std_content00">
            <h4>Welcome to Website</h4>
               <p>Your new login details are:</p>
               <p>Email address: [Email Address]</p>
               <p>Password: [Password]</p>
```

Sending the file to the webservices which sends the email along with the HTML page
  //call the webservice to send email to the newly created user
                    ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient();
                    service.sendEmail(newuseremail, subject, BODY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's not elegant nor the best solution, but it's fast and easy:

```
BODY = BODY
       .Replace("[Email Address]", email)
       .Replace("[Password]", password);
File.WriteAllText(newFilename, BODY);
```

Just a suggestion: to read BODY variable you'd better using

```
string BODY = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

without the need to use streams (I think your email template is short...)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get data in your string variable `BODY`, you can do `BODY.Replace("[Email Address]","...")`.